# Dynamically reading column headers to pass to ETL Metadata Injection step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Having difficulty understanding how to dynamically pass the headers of any csv to the Metadata Injection step.

I mostly get how it works.  However, the examples out there create the field definitions from the 'Meta' tab of a data grid, and pass the column headers via the 'Data' tab of the same data grid.  Thus, you have to know the column names, which defeats my purpose.

How can I continue to pass the field definitions from the data grid, but pass the header names dynamically?

Comment: `Data Grid` step is more appropriate for small static data and illustration purpose. In a production environment, I'd suggest you avoid `Data Grid` step and use `YAML Input` step with which you can easily maintain all configuration in one place. also add the YAML filename as a parameter for more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the file in two passes:

1. The injector transformation reads the header line only, and parses it to determine the list of available fields (and possibly with a data dictionary to define data types, formats, etc.)
2. A template transformation that reads from the file, but doesn't have any field information. this will be injected on run time.

Here's a working example: http://ubiquis.co.uk/pdi/loading-csv-files-with-pdi-metadata-injection/